# What is the Biblical Basis against the use of profanity?

Tags: biblical-basis, language

It's very common to have a negative perception about cursing, saying swear words (i.e. the use of profanity), among all Christian groups. What is the biblical basis for not swearing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your clarification, I would start by pointing out Ephesians 4 and 5 as condemning cussing.

> Let no unwholesome word come out of your mouth, but if there is any good word for edification according to the need of the moment, say that, so that it will give grace to those who hear. (4:29 NASB)

> and there must be no filthiness or foolish talk, or vulgar joking, which are not fitting, but rather giving of thanks (5:4 NASB)

Comment: And Jesus said "Whatever comes out of your mouth is what defiles you", you could probably add that one too.